# Uncaught ReferenceError: submitAllForms is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

All.

Please see the following code, which should, as far as I can gather, grab IDs a1, a2 & a3, and throw them in the new textbox with the ID 'compiled':

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitAllForms() {           
var answer1 = (document.getElementById("a1").value);
var answer2 = (document.getElementById("a2").value);
var answer3 = (document.getElementById("a3").value);           
document.getElementById("compiler").innerHTML = ("<input type="text" id="compiled">" + "Question1? " + answer1 + " Question2? " + answer2 + " Question3? " + answer3 + "\nEnd" + "</input>");
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form id="q1" method="post">
<p>Question1?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a1" />
</form>
<form id="q2" method="post">
<p>Question2?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a2" />
</form>
<form id="q3" method="post">
<p>Question3?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a3" />
</form>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitAllForms()" />
<form id="compiler" method="post">
</form>
</body>
```

The problem I've got is that upon hitting the submit button, the console spits out the error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: submitAllForms is not defined*

Which to me doesn't make sense. I can't see where I've gone wrong.
Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works for me. Where is your script placed? Is it within the same HTML file as the rest of your code?

Comment: It is in the <head> section of the same file, yes.
Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've syntax error in javascript. You need to delete `"` (what is bad idea), or escape it using `\`, as below:

```
function submitAllForms() {           
var answer1 = (document.getElementById("a1").value);
var answer2 = (document.getElementById("a2").value);
var answer3 = (document.getElementById("a3").value);           
document.getElementById("compiler").innerHTML = ("<input type=\"text\" id=\"compiled\">" + "Question1? " + answer1 + " Question2? " + answer2 + " Question3? " + answer3 + "\nEnd" + "</input>");
}
```

It's good idea to use editor with syntax highlighting. After fast copy–paste I seen that parts of code which should be strings, but they wasn't.

Escaping special characters ([see more in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)) let you use quotes etc. inside strings just as normal characters in it.

Comment: Thanks. That must have been the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work OK.  Tidied up a bit to remove errors with the string concatenation, but the function is called by the code as written.

```js
function submitAllForms() {           
var answer1 = document.getElementById("a1").value;
var answer2 = document.getElementById("a2").value;
var answer3 = document.getElementById("a3").value; 

document.getElementById("compiler").innerHTML = "<input type=text id=compiled>Question1? " + answer1 + " Question2? " + answer2 + " Question3? " + answer3 + "\nEnd</input>";
}
```

```html
<body>
<form id="q1" method="post">
<p>Question1?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a1" />
</form>
<form id="q2" method="post">
<p>Question2?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a2" />
</form>
<form id="q3" method="post">
<p>Question3?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="answer" id="a3" />
</form>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitAllForms()" />
<form id="compiler" method="post">
</form>
</body>
```